# Calling WCF service from winform/ASP.net jquery ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, wcf, nettcpbinding

Hey all I have the following code that sends a json string via jQuery AJAX call to my asp.net code behind and places it into their class names.

JavaScript Ajax:
[image]

ASP.net code behind:
[image]

The WCF code:
[image]

The code for the AJAX:

```
$("#WCF").on("click", function () {
    var scannerSettings = {
        "FileType": "TEST1",
        "FileName": "C:\Program Files (x86)\somethibg\Sample\ScanTest\VCS 2008\bin\Debug\image#####",//$('').text(),
        "JpegQuality": "TEST2",
        "ScanContinue": false,
        "Resolution": "TEST3",
        "Rotation": "TEST4",
        "PaperSupply": "TEST5",
        "PaperSize": "TEST6",
        "Orientation": "TEST7",
        "CustomPaperWidth": 8.268,
        "CustomPaperLength": 11.693,
        "JobControl": "TEST8",
        "PunchHoleRemoval": "TEST9"
    };

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType    : "json",
        url         : ajaxDirPath + "WCF",
        data        : JSON.stringify({ "obj": scannerSettings }),
        cache       : false,
        success     : ServiceSucceeded,
        error       : ServiceFailed
    });
});
```

ASP.net code behind code (HomeController.cs):

```
[HttpPost]
[Audit(EventTypeName = "{controller}/{action} ({verb})", IncludeHeaders = true, IncludeModel = true)]
public string WCF(scannerSettings obj)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> resultsBack = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointAddress"].ToString()));
    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    ChannelFactory<IService1> factory;
    IService1 SvcCall;

    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);
    SvcCall = factory.CreateChannel();

    string scanerData = SvcCall.Scan(obj);

    if (scanerData != null)
    {
        resultsBack.Add("dback", "GOOD");
        resultsBack.Add("img", "");
        resultsBack.Add("filename", obj.FileName);
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultsBack, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

The WCF code:

```
public string Scan(scannerSettings obj)
{
    TestDelegate d = new TestDelegate(startScan);
    IAsyncResult ar = d.BeginInvoke(obj, null, null);

    string result = d.EndInvoke(ar);

    return result;
```

}

As you can see from the images above, it sends the data fine from **AJAX->HomeController.cs** but once I send it again to the WCF server like **AJAX->HomeController.cs->WCF** it no longer has the needed values - they are all **null**.

The json class:

```
[DataContract]
public class scannerSettings
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string JpegQuality { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool ScanContinue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Rotation { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PaperSupply { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PaperSize { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Orientation { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CustomPaperWidth { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CustomPaperLength { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string JobControl { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PunchHoleRemoval { get; set; }
}
```

I'm connecting to the WCF service locally using **NetTcpBinding** via this address:

> net.tcp://localhost:2202/theService/tech6140

Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: I once had this issue when the namespace of the object being transferred was different between the server and client, so the fully-qualified type name did not match and the WCF service didn't recognize it.

Comment: @DanWilson can you show an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: Server saw `scannerSettings` as `Org.Code.scannerSettings` while client saw it as `ServiceProxy.scannerSettings`. I'm assuming the client is using `scannerSettings` as part of the generated proxy class.

Comment: @DanWilson an example would be better.

Comment: I don't get where you are getting **Org.Code.scannerSettings** and **ServiceProxy.scannerSettings**?

Comment: That was my example; I just made up those namespaces.

Comment: @DanWilson  that makes more since then. You’re suggestion worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service may not recognize the request object as `scannerSettings` if the class' namespace is different on the server and the client. I made this mistake a few weeks ago.

On the server, I had the request object

```
Acme.Service.RequestObject
```

When I generated the service proxy, it included the request object. I changed the namespace on the client for aesthetic reasons to

```
SomeCoolNamespace.Service.RequestObject
```

When calling the service, the service will receive a request object whose namespace does not match the expected namespace, and the parameter will be null.